# Populating map from multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, guava, concurrenthashmap

I have a ConcurrentHashMap which I am populating from multiple threads as shown below:

```
private static Map<ErrorData, Long> holder = new ConcurrentHashMap<ErrorData, Long>();

public static void addError(ErrorData error) {
    if (holder.keySet().contains(error)) {
        holder.put(error, holder.get(error) + 1);
    } else {
        holder.put(error, 1L);
    }
}
```

Is there any possibility of race condition in above code and it can skip updates? Also how can I use Guava [AtomicLongMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AtomicLongMap.html) here if that can give better performance?

I am on Java 7.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a possibility of a race because you are not checking contains and putting atomically.

You can use `AtomicLongMap` as follows, which does this check atomically:

```
private static final AtomicLongMap<ErrorData> holder = AtomicLongMap.create();

public static void addError(ErrorData error) {
  holder.getAndIncrement(error);
}
```

As described in the javadoc:

> [T]he typical mechanism for writing to this map is addAndGet(K, long), which adds a long to the value currently associated with K. If a key has not yet been associated with a value, its implicit value is zero.

and

> All operations are atomic unless otherwise noted.

Comment: if you see my example, I have a Long value as well in the map which I am incrementing for each unique key.. At the end I am printing out this map and it prints out like this `{SomeKey=3}`

Comment: @user1950349, yes?  That makes sense; you can still use `AtomicLongMap` for that.

Comment: btw I am seeing this error while initializing `AtomicLongMap`: `Cannot infer type arguments for AtomicLongMap<>`

Comment: @user1950349 `AtomicLongMap` is like a `Map<ErrorData, Long>`. You can get an actual `Map<ErrorData, Long>` by calling `holder.asMap()`.

Comment: I see what you mean... Let me play with it little bit.. Its slightly new so I was confuse.. thanks for explaining that.

Comment: How do I fix this error `Cannot infer type arguments for AtomicLongMap<>`?

Comment: Give it actual type arguments: `new AtomicLongMap<ErrorData>()`. It ought to be able to infer that, though.

Comment: Do we need to create like this `private static final AtomicLongMap<ErrorData> holder = AtomicLongMap.create();`?

Comment: Or it should be `getAndIncrement` or `incrementAndGet`?

Comment: @user1950349 please read the Javadoc and determine which is the most appropriate (hint: is there an observable difference between the statements `i++;` and `++i;` for some long `i`?)

Comment: @user1950349, if you're not reading out the result it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using java 8, you can take advantage of the new [`merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method:

```
holder.merge(error, 1L, Long::sum);
```

Comment: I am still on Java 7. Forgot to mention.. Let me update my question.

Answer (score 4):

A 'vanilla' java 5+ solution :

```
public static void addError(final ErrorData errorData) {
    Long previous = holder.putIfAbsent(errorData, 1L);
    // if the error data is already mapped to some value
    if (previous != null) {
        // try to replace the existing value till no update takes place in the meantime
        while (!map.replace(errorData, previous, previous + 1)) {
            previous = map.get(errorData);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java 7 or older versions you need to use a compare-and-update loop:

```
Long prevValue;
boolean done;
do {
  prevValue = holder.get(error);
  if (prevValue == null) {
    done = holder.putIfAbsent(error, 1L);
  } else {
    done = holder.replace(error, prevValue, newValue);
  }
} while (!done);
```

With this code, if two threads race one may end up retrying its update, but they'll get the right value in the end.

Consider:

```
Thread1: holder.get(error) returns 1
Thread2: holder.get(error) returns 1
Thread1: holder.put(error, 1+1);
Thread2: holder.put(error, 1+1);
```

To fix this you need to use atomic operations to update the map.

Comment: Isn't this the same as my answer ?

Comment: @Bax yes but I didn't noticed it you posted already.. I just saw it.